# Why does grep match my regex lazily?

Tags: regex, email, grep, email-validation, regex-greedy

I am trying to write a simple e-mail regex, and extract the e-mail itself with grep (on Kali linux, if that matters).
This is (roughly) my code:

```
email_regex='([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-])+)'
egrep -o "$email_regex" e
```

Where e is a file containing an e-mail address, such as "a@b.co.uk"

The egrep returns "a@b.c".

I tried the following regexes:

- `([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_-]\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` - returned "a@b.co"
- `([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)` - returned "a@b.co.uk", but also detects "a@b..com" as a valid address, and I don't want that.
- A few other things that also didn't produce good results

Everywhere I looked, I only found questions of how to make grep match lazily, since the default is supposed to be greedy..

Comment: Btw. this is a valid e-mail address, too: `foo@[1.2.3.4]`

Comment: How about `email_regex='([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){2,})'`. This will exclude `a@b.com` and as a side-efftect will also exclude `email@gmail.com`. In regex, `+` means 1 or more, but you need 2 or more according to your post, hence `{2,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
email_regex='[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+'
```

In your regex, last character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` is missing quantifier `+`